# Solving surface integral using divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

**Here is the problem:**

Use divergence theorem to compute [image]

$S$ is boundary of solid bounded above cone $z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ below sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$.

**Here is my solving process:**

When setting up the integral, the bounds I chose are

- $ 0 <r < \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ , upper bound from 2 solid's intersection
- $ 0< \theta <2\pi$
- $ 0 < z <\sqrt{1-r^2}$, upper bound comes from equation of sphere

Then the $\nabla \cdot F = x^2+y^2+z^2$, and $dV = rdzdrd\theta$.

**Here is my confusion:**

The result I've got is incorrect, and the only problem I can think of is the lower bound of $z$. It might be $r$ (coming from the equation of cone) instead of $0$ but why? The bounded solid E starts from origin, isn't it? Hope someone will answer my doubt.

Plus, are there any other problems in my solving process? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I should split the surface S? but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divergence is correct. The problem as you mentioned is with the lower bound of $z$. In cylindrical coordinates, the integral should be set up as -

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{1/ \sqrt 2}\int_r^{\sqrt{1-r^2}} r(r^2+z^2) \, dz \, dr \, d\theta$

On your question as to why the lower bound should be $r$ and not $0$, first deal with the cone with base as $z = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \,$ and vertex at the origin, without the spherical cap on top. For a given $r$, can $z$ freely vary between $0$ and $1 / \sqrt2$? That will give you the volume of the cylinder instead of the cone. In a cone, $z$ can vary from the base to the points on its rays, ($r \leq z \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$). Now the upper bound of $z$ changes because we are just adding the spherical cap on top.

In spherical coordinates which is easier in this case,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^1 r^4 \sin \phi \, dr \, d\phi \, d\theta$

Comment: understand it now, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome!